# How can I open a FileInputStream that has its share set to allow ReadWrite?

Tags: java, java.nio.file

In .Net I can open a FileStream set to FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite. How can I do the same in Java?

Files.newInoutStream() does not appear to support either of these capabilities.

**Update:** Let me explain why. We have a common use case where our application opens a DOCX file while Word has it opening for editing. The only way Windows allows this due to the locks Word has on the file is FileAccess.Read & FileShare.ReadWrite.

And yes, that's dangerous (would be fine if it was FileShare.Read). But the world is what it is here and this in practice works great.

But it means I need to find a way in Java to open an InputStream to that file that the existing constraints due to Word holding it open require.

Comment: [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) may help here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'InoutStream' in java.

You're probably looking for `Files.newByteChannel`:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class Snippet {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path path = Paths.get("test.txt");
    try (var channel = Files.newByteChannel(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
      ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
      channel.read(bb);
      // Note that 'read' reads 1 to x bytes depending on file system and
      // phase of the moon.
      bb.flip();
      System.out.println("Read: " + StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(bb));
      bb.clear();

      channel.position(0);
      channel.write(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode("Hello, World!"));

      channel.position(0);
      channel.read(bb);
      bb.flip();
      System.out.println("Read: " + StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(bb));
    }
  }
}
```

make a file named 'test.txt', put in whatever you like, then run this. It'll print whatever is there, then overwrite it with Hello, World!.

Note that the read call is guaranteed to read at least 1 byte, but will not neccessarily fill the entire buffer even if the file is that large: The idea is that you read one 'block' that the OS and file system can efficiently transfer in one operation. You'll need to add some loops if you want to read a guaranteed minimum, or even the entire file.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my questions because I realized without the why behind the question people were not understanding my core issue. What I need is the open to occure with rights that Windows will allow when Word has the same file open.

Comment: Well, Files.newByteChannel and company will do it, just.. don't include the WRITE tag. As long as another process has the file open on windows (even if only for reading), you can't normally also open it for writing.